# Export PostgreSQL DB with only 100 records per table

Tags: pgadmin, postgresql-9.6

I'm workink on rails app with postgreSQL database.

The database has differents schemas. One of them stores reference datas and is used in read-only mode.
In development and production environment, datas are loaded from a flat file datas.SQL .

As it is a very large file, for my test environment, I would like to make a light version of it.
From the development database, could i export a .sql flat file with only this schema and only 100 records per tables ?

Comment: http://jailer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Have you already been using it for such use ? couldn't find how to export all tables from the same schema  with only 100 records. thanks